# How to format output using racket

Tags: format, racket

How do I format output using racket? I want to output a fixed-width number and fill it with 0 if the width is too small? How can I do it? I have searched the racket documentation but I can only find `fprintf`, which seems to be unable to do it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use functions from the [`racket/format`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html?q=~a#%28mod-path._racket%2Fformat%29) module. For example `~a`:

```
#lang racket
(require racket/format)
(~a 42 
    #:align 'right
    #:width 4
    #:pad-string "0")
```

returns

```
"0042"
```

Answer (score 4):

`format` in `#!racket` isn't as rich as `sprintf` in C languages. A workaroundwould eb to do it yourself:

```scm
(require srfi/13)
(string-pad (number->string 23) 4 #\0) ; ==> "0023"
```